# CSS - Display images side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web page that shows pictures of cute dogs. For every dog, I want to show the name of the dog and then a picture below it.

I would like the images to be shown side by side, but they are shown stacked vertically.

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/53bnhscm/2/

Here is my HTML

```
<h1>Listing dogs</h1>

<ul>
  <li> Dog 1 </li></br>
  <li>
    <a href="/dogs/2">
      <img alt="Dog 1" src="http://renterswarehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Cute-Dog-dogs-13286656-1024-768-200x200.jpg" />
    </a>        
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li> Dog 2 </li></br>
  <li>
    <a href="/dogs/3">
      <img alt="Dog 2" src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/1D8A5A9AD81112510785588019200_21ff866832a.1.0.jpg?versionId=0I_eiPNigLBtjlgOMJIQyCYY4fKf2YNs" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

I thought a `break` statement after every list item and a `display:inline` property would do the trick, but I guess not.

Comment: _“I thought a break statement after every list item”_ – that is invalid HTML. `ul` can contain only `li` as child elements, not other structural markup such as `br`.

Comment: There are loads of ways to do that. Describing even the most important alternatives would require a much longer answer than fits the SO format, not to mention discussing the pros and cons, which depend on the context (overall layout, amount and size of pictures, interest in responsive design, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Your `li`s are contained within their own `ul` so you need to inline that instead.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; //use instead of inline
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/53bnhscm/3/)

Also `li` tags are more for list items so this isn't a real efficient way of doing this. Plus its a lot of extra code. You could simply wrap your sections in a container and inline that:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Listing dogs</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
    Dog 1
    <a href="/dogs/2">
       <img alt="Dog 1" src="..." />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   Dog 2
   <a href="/dogs/3">
      <img alt="Dog 2" src="..." />
   </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper a{
    display: block;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/53bnhscm/6/)

Comment: Don't forget to add `font-size: 0;` to `.wrapper`s' parent to avoid blank space between images and override it for each `.wrapper`.

Comment: `.wrapper` is the parent and which blank space are you referring to?

Comment: Compare your jsFiddle and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/p996hwrw/1/). Pay attention to spaces between images.

Comment: @Kiril OP asked for side by side but didnt specify whether or not that meant the images should be touching. He/she would have to specify, yes you can use that (although that and other methods to remove the spacing from inline-blocks is a bit hacky) or use simple floats

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `display: table-cell` to `ul` elements:

```css
ul {
  display: table-cell;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Listing dogs</h1>

<ul>
  <li>Dog 1</li>
  </br>
  <li>
    <a href="/dogs/2">
      <img alt="Dog 1" src="http://renterswarehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Cute-Dog-dogs-13286656-1024-768-200x200.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Dog 2</li>
  </br>
  <li>
    <a href="/dogs/3">
      <img alt="Dog 2" src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/1D8A5A9AD81112510785588019200_21ff866832a.1.0.jpg?versionId=0I_eiPNigLBtjlgOMJIQyCYY4fKf2YNs" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a fiddle. Your markup is messy by the way, I recommend to use HTML5 markup `<figure>` so you can easily add a `<figcaption>`: http://jsfiddle.net/53bnhscm/7/

```
<h1>Listing dogs</h1>

<figure>
    <figcaption>Dog 1</figcaption>
    <img alt="Dog 1" src="http://renterswarehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Cute-Dog-dogs-13286656-1024-768-200x200.jpg" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <figcaption>Dog2</figcaption>
    <img alt="Dog 2" src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/1D8A5A9AD81112510785588019200_21ff866832a.1.0.jpg?versionId=0I_eiPNigLBtjlgOMJIQyCYY4fKf2YNs" />
</figure>
```

CSS

```
figure {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul > li {
  list-style: none;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 5px;
}
```

And I think may be you are looking something like this. In that case you have to edit your html code 
http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadsharif/p0cbmy2h/

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is correct for your markup.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; //use instead of inline
}
```

But if you mean exactly what is written in your question then one thing that I need to mention and it is “You should take care of your HTML markup.”

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/dogs/2">
      <b>Dog 1</b>
      <img alt="Dog 1" src="http://renterswarehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Cute-Dog-dogs-13286656-1024-768-200x200.jpg" />
    </a>        
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="/dogs/3">
      <b>Dog 2</b>
      <img alt="Dog 2" src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/avatars/1D8A5A9AD81112510785588019200_21ff866832a.1.0.jpg?versionId=0I_eiPNigLBtjlgOMJIQyCYY4fKf2YNs" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then your CSS will be:

```
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a b{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use UIKIT and its grid system. This way they will stack automatically on phones.

http://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html

```
<div class="uk-grid">
<div class="uk-width-1-2">Your Image HERE</div>
<div class="uk-width-1-2">Another Image Here</div>
</div>
```